# QGIS - How to avoid -2147483648 value from imported CSV?

Tags: qgis, csv, attribute-joins, import

I am attempting to join a spreadsheet containing all the CIA Factbook Country Comparison Data (many columns) to the existing Natural Earth world countries shapefile.  I followd the tutorial [here](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/using-tabular-data-in-qgis.html), but a couple of things occurred:

1)  Several of bits of data were changed to -2147483648

2)  The imported field lengths all show as "0" in the properties.

I am not trained in GIS and I have never worked with databases.  I am simply trying to combine this data and shapefile, so that my students will be able to graphically manipulate and analyze the information in a new Global Studies course.

I've tried taking the spreadsheet (from Excel) and putting it through Access and then exporting to a dbf file.  I have set all the field lengths to 100 (and even tried 50), but I get a "field will not fit in record" error.  I even tried truncating the column headings to 10 (thinking that might have been the problem, based on internet searches), but it didn't help.

---

As Per Comment:

Here is a [link to a version of the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzHj6AzbbxcIZGdXZVJ0aE5NT3c/edit?usp=sharing) with truncated headings.

Here is a picture of the corrupt data.
https:// docs . google . com/file/d/0BzHj6AzbbxcINy1jTGRPTDh1bFU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show a sample of the problematic CIA Factbook spreadsheet? Have you tried loading the CSV using the Add delimited Text layer tool?

Comment: I added a link to a version of the spreadsheet with the truncated headings as well as a link (remove spaces) to a picture of the data corrupted.  I read someone about it the corrupted data being related to the field length.  I didn't use the "Add delimited Text layer tool", since I was following the tutorial listed above.  Again, I am not trained in GIS and I am learning the basics to be able to help my students evaluation/interpret/manipulate data, not actually create detailed GIS-based maps from scratch.  There are 8th graders, hehehe. :-)

Comment: It's well possible that the values are too large. You might want to try to devide by 1 million to create smaller values to work with.

Comment: So, for some reason, QGIS doesn't like to import numbers that are in the billions?  With Economic data, there is going to be a lot of them.  I will have to find a way to batch edit it then.

Comment: I've had similar issues with Shapefiles that contained very large integer IDs. It seems to be an issue of the underlying OGR driver. That's why I asked if you tried Add delimited text layer because it is independent of OGR.

Comment: I tried after you suggested, but since there is no XY data, I don't believe it worked.  I'm trying to modify the spreadsheet in Excel to reduce items to Millions, but I will have to also modify the headers to reflect the scale, otherwise students won't understand the numbers.

Comment: Oh right, functionality to add CSVs without x/y columns was only added after QGIS 1.8 ...

Comment: I am using 1.8.0, but it required x/y or WKT field.